# How to serve dynamic sitemap.xml through nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, wagtail

How to serve dynamic sitemap.xml file (generated from a CMS) through nginx? Is there any rules that have to be configured?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is a django question but perhaps this helps: https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-sitemap